# Best practice for updating a software that was installed via `checkinstall`

Tags: apt, updates, checkinstall

One of the recommended practices to install a software from source is using `checkinstall` because it's easier to remove the software later.

But what's the best practice for updating such a software?

Should I remove the installed .deb package first and install the updated software again via `checkinstall`? Or can I directly install the software again and the system will automatically recognize that there is an old version of this software installed and overwrite it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crucial installation option with checkinstall is the `--pkgversion` option. If this is set correctly:

1. A lesser version of your checkinstall-installed software  *will not* overwrite a more recent version of your software application
2. A more recent version *will* replace your checkinstall-installed software application

In this way checkinstall integrates very nicely with the Ubuntu package management system, and this system will automatically make room for a checkinstall produced package.

You do not necessarily have to specify this option on the commandline as checkinstall will normally do a great job of finding the correct version number...